# `make` Javascript compiling/testing

Tags: javascript, testing

Is there a library intended for compiling/testing your Javascript libraries?

I've noticed many common Javascript libraries like jQuery still use gnu make.  Nothing is wrong with the traditional `make`, but I was just curious if a solution in Javascript has been crafted.

Obviously using `node.js` you can easily `fs.readFile` and then `concat` the files but it is often nice to look at others source who have more experience on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your looking for [`Ender`](http://ender.no.de/). It's a package manager for client-side javascript.

You define your package in your standard `package.json` file and then use the command line `ender` API to construct and build your javascript package.

Comment: Ender looks pretty sweet.  Is it intended do more then concat and manage files?  For example like feature testing.  I'm suprised there isn't a library that's geared toward feature testing and building/making files.

Comment: @Lime feature testing? Are you looking for a command line tool or something to run in the browser? [`yepnope`](http://yepnopejs.com/) and [`boxjs`](http://boxjs.com/) might be what your looking for

Comment: Thanks for the info Raynos.  As reference for others viewing this question I also found `jake` a Javascript `make` on github.